# SSRS - display some data once and other records need to display all

Tags: ssrs-tablix, ssrs-grouping, ssrs-2008-r2

i have a report i am creating, the data looks like this in the database:

MF5059DD    PEPPERED EGG 192 / 1.9 OZ   2014-03-08  3   0   84.0000

MF5059DD    PEPPERED EGG 192 / 1.9 OZ   2014-03-10  3   0   -6.0000

MF5059DD    PEPPERED EGG 192 / 1.9 OZ   2014-03-12  3   0   -2.0000

i need to display the part ID (MF5059DD) and description only once, and then the transaction date and the quantity adjustment i need to show each as a separate line item.

it should look like this:

MF5059DD    PEPPERED EGG 192 / 1.9 OZ

2014-03-08  3   0   84.0000

2014-03-10  3   0   -6.0000

2014-03-12  3   0   -2.0000

i have a tablix set up and in the first row  i have the part id header info, then a second row has the details, however, when i run the report, its doing the opposite of what i want listing all the part id's and descriptions 11 times, and only one of the date records.

i have no groups set up other than the default "Details" that is made when i create the report.

how can i get the data to only display the part and description once and the transactions multiple times when its all one record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a group above details which groups on part ID